# Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on resource project cloudtasks_queue

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-iam

#### Info

I'm trying to setup a Google Cloud Task queue using Terraform. The infrastructure is set up, however when I make an HTTP request to the queue I don't have sufficient permissions.

#### Error

`Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on resource project migration-job-queue.`

[image]

#### Setup

##### Terraform

```hcl
# Queue
resource "google_cloud_tasks_queue" "migration_job_queue" {
  project  = google_project.project.project_id
  name     = "migration-job-queue"
  location = var.gcp_region

  rate_limits {
    max_dispatches_per_second = 1
    max_concurrent_dispatches = 2
  }
}

# Permissions for terraform
resource "google_cloud_tasks_queue_iam_binding" "binding_admin" {
  project  = google_cloud_tasks_queue.migration_job_queue.project
  location = google_cloud_tasks_queue.migration_job_queue.location
  name     = google_cloud_tasks_queue.migration_job_queue.name
  role     = "roles/cloudtasks.viewer"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${var.gcp_terraform_service_account}",
  ]
}

# Permission for service account (used in code)
resource "google_service_account" "local_service_account" {
  account_id   = var.gcp_personal_service_account
  display_name = "Service account to be downloaded"
  project      = google_project.project.project_id

  depends_on = [
    google_project_service.service
  ]
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "service_account_member" {
  project = google_project.project.project_id

  for_each = toset([
    "roles/owner"
  ])

  role   = each.key
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.local_service_account.email}"

  depends_on = [
    google_service_account.local_service_account
  ]
}
```

##### Permissions

Currently my service account that I'm using to make the HTTP requests has `roles/owner` privileges.

#### Code

```
@Injectable()
class QueueService {

    private client: CloudTasksClient;

    constructor() {
        this.client = new CloudTasksClient({
            projectId: process.env.GCP_PROJECT_ID,
            // --------------------------------------
            // NOTE: My service account exported to a file (works for other services)
            // --------------------------------------
            keyFilename: process.env.GCP_KEY, 
        });
    }

    public async list(task: QueueTask) {

        // --------------------------------------
        // NOTE: This function causes the error.
        // --------------------------------------
        const list = await this.client.listQueues({
            parent: task.name,
        });
    }
}

export default QueueService;
```

#### How can you help me?

Does anyone have more insights on what this error exactly means? Or why it's caused?

#### Updates

##### 1. 8 hour debug journey

Still nothing found, disabled and enabled the CloudTask API again. Didn't do anything.